# EF (entity framework) usage of "using" statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, garbage-collection, dbcontext, using-statement

I have a project on MVC. We chose EF for our DB transactions. We created some managers for the BLL layer. I found a lot of examples, where "`using`" statement is used, i.e.

```
public Item GetItem(long itemId)
    {
        using (var db = new MyEntities())
        {
            return db.Items.Where(it => it.ItemId == itemId && !it.IsDeleted).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Here we create a new instance of DBcontext `MyEntities()`.
We using "`using`" in order to ["ensure the correct use of IDisposable objects."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

It's only one method in my manager. But I have more than ten of them.
Every time I call any method from the manager I'll be using "`using`" statement and  create another DBcontext in the memory. When will the garbage collector (GC) dispose them? Does anyone know?

But there is alternative usage of the manager methods.
We create a global variable:

```
private readonly MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
```

and use DBcontext in every method without "`using`" statement. And method looks like this:

```
public Item GetItem(long itemId)
{
    return db.Items.Where(it => it.ItemId == itemId && !it.IsDeleted).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Questions:

1. What is the proper way of using DBcontext variable?
2. What if we wouldn't use "`usage`" statement (because it affects the performance) - GC will do all for that?

I'm a "rookie" in EF usage and still haven't found the unequivocal answer for this question.

Comment: Depends how far you want to take it. Ideally you wouldn't instantiate it in your controller at all but instead **Inject** it (IoC/DI) that way whatever is calling controller (Factory) can determine lifetime of Context.

Comment: Why does it affect performance? Have you measured it, and concluded that your are losing performance? And the GC is not disposing it, you are disposing it yourself since you are using using-statements.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you will find many suggesting this style of pattern. Not just me or Henk
[DBContext handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737)

- Yes, Ideally Using statements for DBContext subtypes
- Even better Unit Of Work patterns that are managed with Using, that have a context and dispose the context [Just 1 of many UoW examples, this one from Tom Dykstra](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
- The Unit Of Work Manager should be New each Http request
- The context is NOT thread safe so make sure each thread has its own context.
- Let EF cache things behind the scenes.
- Test Context creation times. after several Http request.  Do you still have a concern?
- Expect problems if you store the context in static. any sort of concurrent access will hurt and if you are using parallel AJAX calls, assume 90+% chance of problems if using a static single context.

[For some performance tips, well worth a read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853)

Comment: By the way "Just 1 of many UoW examples, this one from Julie Lerman" is by Tom Dykstra not Julie Lerman

Comment: So performance is better by creating new db context objects, and disposing with `using`, than to re-use the same object?

Comment: no performance isnt better with `using`, well it can be if it prevented a memory leak.  But the point is, Its done for stabililty. You avoid problems.

Answer (score 4):

The proper or best practice way of using DBContext variable is with the Using.

```
    using (var db = new MyEntities())
    {
        return db.Items.Where(it => it.ItemId == itemId && !it.IsDeleted).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The benefit is many things are done automatically for us. For example once the block of code is completed the dispose is called.

Per [MSDN EF Working with DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737)

> The lifetime of the context begins when the instance is created and
>   ends when the instance is either disposed or garbage-collected. Use
>   using if you want all the resources that the context controls to be
>   disposed at the end of the block. When you use using, the compiler
>   automatically creates a try/finally block and calls dispose in the
>   finally block.